# Why isn't my website in Google search results?

Tags: google-search, search-engine-indexing, google-index

It's been sometime and Google has yet to index my site. How can I get Google to index my website?

Comment: The following link will take you to the `seomoz.org` blog, where two days ago, an excellent post was written regarding "missing page audits", and figuring out exactly what's causing your issue. Check it out. [10 Minute Missing Page Audit](http://www.seomoz.org/blog/10-minute-missing-page-audit)

Answer (score 41, accepted):

This is not uncommon as there is [no time frame for Google to index a website](https://sites.google.com/site/webmasterhelpforum/en/faq--crawling--indexing---ranking). The best thing you can do is to give Google every opportunity to find you.

Try all of the following:

1. Submit your website to [Google](http://www.google.com/addurl/?continue=/addurl).
2. Submit an [XML sitemap](http://www.sitemaps.org/). You can do that from within your [Webmaster Control panel](https://support.google.com/sites/answer/100283?hl=en). Most content management systems have a sitemap generator of some sort via their online plugin library's i.e [Drupal add on](http://drupal.org/project/xmlsitemap), [WordPress](https://wordpress.org/plugins/search.php?q=sitemap) and [Joomla](http://extensions.joomla.org/category/structure-a-navigation/site-map).
3. Get [incoming links](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backlink) to your website. Google discovers new website by following links. Submitting your site to directories is a good start. Ideally you'll get a link, or links, from established websites with similar content.
4. Check your [robots.txt](http://www.robotstxt.org/) file and make sure it isn't blocking your home page or entire website.
5. You should also do a fetch test to ensure that your pages are not being blocked via your server response or that of the source code i.e using a nofollow attribute. You can test this by using [Google's fetch url tool](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6066467?hl=en) found within your Google Webmaster account.

Additionally, your site may be partially indexed but not yet ranked, you can check this by doing the following search command in Google Search: `site:example.com`.

Answer (score 9):

Google periodically scan web. Might be your site is not scanned till now.

**Checklist**

1. Ensure your [robots.txt](http://www.robotstxt.org/) file is not blocking Google.
2. Ensure your pages are linked and are crawler-able by Google's Bot
3. Ensure sitemap.xml is located in the correct path or if using a custom page then you will need to manually submit it too Google and other search engines.

Answer (score 6):

Don't forget the concept of domain aging either.  If you slap up a new site on a brand new Domain name, expect Google and the others to de-emphasize it for a time period of at least several months.  This doesn't explain flat out omission as you're seeing, but it does explain why it's incredibly uncommon to see a site shoot directly to the top of the search rankings.

I've had sites that I put a ton of time into not make Google for several weeks or even a month and I tried every (ethical) trick in the book. Eventually, they get picked up and because of all the extra work I did, they moved right up the page in a hurry. I personally subscribe to the idea that SEO is not rocket science, and the only people who REALLY know exactly what will move you up is Google and they're not telling. Google will put you on when Google wants to, provided you make every effort to make their life easier. Bing in my experience has been faster; go figure.

My most successful clients actually get more traffic from social media. If you really need traffic, try promoting yourself consistently everywhere you can (but don't carpet bomb forums, because that's annoying!).

While you're waiting for it to get indexed. Do a W3 check. Take a few days to do extensive testing add a cool new feature you've not gotten around to writing yet. Analyze and add to your (Google discoverable) content buy your significant other dinner, walk the dog.

Answer (score 3):

Possible reasons include:

1. You have `noindex` on your pages (view the source to check)
2. You're blocking search engines indexing it via the robots.txt file
3. The search engines have not discovered your site yet (wait 1-4 weeks - backlinks help)
4. The site is indexed but your expecting Webmaster Tools in either Bing or Google to reflect these indexes, Webmaster Tools are not real time stats
5. It is indexed but under a variation that you do not expect, see below.
6. You site is doing the Google Dance or Sandbox.

> [SOURCE](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/68435/moving-from-http-to-https-in-google-search-console/68436#68436)
>
> *Add all variations of your site to WMT*
>
> While the site address move tool may not treat protocols, url changes
> and sub domains as new sites, the rest of Webmaster Tools does treat
> protocols and sub domains as separate sites. You should add all
> variations of your site, below is an example of my site BYBE added to
> WMT with all variations, you should do the same. (recommended by [John
> Mueller](https://plus.google.com/%20JohnMueller/posts) from Google, See comments below this answer).

[image: bybe multiple sites in webmaster tools]
<sub>(source: [bybe.net](https://www.bybe.net/files/pro-webmasters/bybe-multiple-sites-in-google-webmaster-tools.png))</sub>

Answer (score 3):

Not all of the pages get crawled - Google does not look at everything.

Use the [Fetch as Google tool](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/googlebot-fetch) to fetch and then index the missing pages.

[You should also submit a sitemap to Google Webmaster tools.](https://support.google.com/sites/answer/100283?hl=en)