# My Blog not not showing in Google Search Results

Tags: seo, google-search, blogger, blog

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [I cannot see my website in google](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/2402/i-cannot-see-my-website-in-google)

Hello Everyone,
yesterday, i created two [blog](http://zahidadeel.blogspot.com/) entries and published them on blogger but it is not showing up in google search results. How long do i have to wait before i can see it in google search results (before google crawls the blog). i have already shared the address on couple of sites and there are almost 80 page views from three different referrals. Any help/suggestion is highly appreciated.
regards

Answer (score 1):

There is no way of telling how long it will be. I'm not surprised that they aren't showing up yet. I suggest you just wait longer.

Comment: thanks for prompt reply. there is no problem in waiting. At least, now i know that i need to wait and problem is not at my end. can you tell how can i reduce this wait. probably seo or any such thing?

Answer (score 1):

The more often you upload new content and the more backlinks you have to your blog the more often Google will index your site.

On one of my blogs when I used to keep it updated daily, I could see new posts in the SERPS within a few hours (possibly sooner but I can't vouch for that). Now that I don't have so much time for this blog and I update it less regularly, articles don't show until the next day.