# Major Indexing problem with my site

Tags: seo, wordpress, google-search, search-engine-indexing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [I cannot see my website in google](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/2402/i-cannot-see-my-website-in-google)

Hey guys I am having problem with indexing my site http://www.loosediamondschicago.com which is in wordpress hosted on godaddy. Its about two weeks but still no search engine indexing me.

**Some Points Your Should Know:**

1. The site hosted in wordpress.
2. When the site was in development I turned off the search engine visibility from the wordpress dashboard. After turned it on I checked the meta tags and i have found no noindex. So, i guess that is not the issue.
3. To my previous experience with wordpress i know wordpress is smart enough to automatically remove the **www** in url but in this case its not.
4. I have sent sitemap via google webmaster tool about 4 days ago but still no indexing. However webmaster tool is showing error for using now **www** url in the sitemap while my urls are **www**. But I believe if i dont have sitemap still my site should be crawled right?
5. The domain client bought was use before by other people but expired couple of years ago then my client again registered it.
6. I have checked if the domain in blacklisted or not. I have found the result not blacklisted.
7. I have get couple of backlinks hoping that my site will get indexed but still no hope.

I did not faced this kinds of problem before. So people please advice. I am now check godaddy to find out if any crawl errors. I will update the post when i have it.

**Update**

The site is up for one and half month but search engine allowed about 2-3 weeks. I blocked the search engine when the site was in development.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's just a matter of time. Have your site being up for just 4 days (see your poinn 4)?

About some of your points:

(3) I'm not WP expert, but certaintly you might find something about how to go and remove the www (maybe in .htaccess). Anyway using www or not does not affect Google, I mean it obviously can index www and not-www sites

(4) 4 days is not a long time, couldn't you wait 10 to 30 days?
Yes your site should be crawled anyway, even without sitemap, as long as you submitted it to Google or Google found a link to your site.

Comment: No, the site is up for about 3-4 weeks now. It is very unusual that google not indexing yet. I have pinged couple of times via pingomatic. I am in this business about 5 years now never seen anything like this :(

Comment: 3-4 weeks are definitely too much if you submitted the sitemap 3-4 weeks ago (you saied you submitetd it 4 days ago). Did you at least submit the site to Google 3-4 weeks ago? [see: http://www.google.com/addurl/?continue=/addurl] If NOT than 3-4 weeks is not too much! In my experience without doing either sitemap or url submission it will take at least 30 days. Google is great, but still not a wizard that can discover your site exists just because you registered a domain.

Comment: Actually site is up for 3-4 weeks but i send the sitemap couple of days ago.

Comment: @Sisir: that's it than. Just wait in 15 days (max 30) you should see your site being indexed.

Comment: Okey, someone closed the thread anyway. I have this other blog http://web.tutremix.com where google index me less then 30 min when I publish a post. Its also new and up for two months. Also i have seen in past that google index in 2 weeks weather i send sitemap or not.

Comment: @Sisir: the time Google takes to reindex a site that was already crawled/indexed by it is different to the time that Google takes to index a new site for the 1st time. If your blog get reindexed by Google in less than 30' it's probably cause Google thinks your blog needs to be reindexed many times maybe cause you updated contents very frequently and Google detected it.

Answer (score 1):

First you should check the webmaster tools and see if there's anything wrong there (crawl errors, fetch as googlebot). In case there are no errors there all you can really do is wait and see. I submitted my sitemap to google and it still took about a week for them to index the pages on my site (the site itself exists for over 4 years now). 2 weeks is definitely not long for google to come and index. Pages i have read have said that they will usually index within 6 weeks, but there's no guarantee of that either.

Just make sure you fix any errors you may have on the site, submit a sitemap if possible, and wait. What you could do, however, to speed up the process is try to get other sites to link to your site, then when google crawls that site they might come over to your site and crawl it. But even that might take a while (and i wouldn't suggest just spamming your url in forums/comments (they also have a nofollow in the comments usually).

Answer (score 1):

There is a setting in the Wordpress menus for choosing to have or not have the www on the domain. Change it to what you want to use and resubmit the sitemap. Also validate both the www and non-www domain in webmaster tools and set the settings in webmaster tools to prefer one over the other.

Be patient. Google doesn't always index new sites quickly. In fact they can be extremely slow unless you get loads of high ranking backlinks. If there's no other errors showing up other than the www/non-www issue in the sitemap, then get on with building the site and google will come by when it comes.