# Pages are not searchable by Google

Tags: seo, google

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [I cannot see my website in google](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/2402/i-cannot-see-my-website-in-google)

After migrating my website (based on Drupal CMS) to WebHosting (it's about two months there), I noticed that my pages aren't searchable by Google. It finds nothing, even though it should clearly find my website. Same thing happens when I want to know the ranking of my website.

Do you know where the fault could be?

Comment: What do you mean "migrating my website to webhosting"? Did you switch hosting providers? Did you just launch the site? Did you switch domain names?

Comment: from localhost to webhosting

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you don't see your site in Google's index is they haven't had a chance to crawl your site and add your pages to their index. It doesn't happen magically or quickly. It takes time for Google to find your pages and then crawl them and then add them to the index. You'll need to be patient while this happens. If you want to speed this process along see [this answer](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/2402/i-cannot-see-my-website-in-google/2403#2403) for tips on how to do that.

Comment: How can I find out that things are working and Google is crawling my website? Can I see some good ranking page (I know only Alexa) that shows me how my page is going in the internet? The page is uploaded on webhosting for about two months