# Site not updating on Google

Tags: google, seo

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [I cannot see my website in google](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/2402/i-cannot-see-my-website-in-google)

I uploaded my site a week ago. Before, I only had "Very Soon" on the server.

Google still shows "Very Soon" even though the content has been new for one week now! I pinged, resubmitted by site, but it still not showing up!

Answer (score 0):

You'll just have to wait for Google to come around to it. It has taken up to 2 months for the changes to reflect in my experience. Which is kind of annoying. I'm not sure there is any other way to get Google to update their crawlers.