# How to make google get to know my domain name

Tags: seo

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [I cannot see my website in google](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/2402/i-cannot-see-my-website-in-google)

I have a strange problem with my website. I have a website, let's say Abcdefg.com.

Website is live for 2 months and google still doesn't know it. While searching for my domain name 'abcdefg', google displays results for similar phrase (abcdef) but not fot mine.

How to make google get to know my domain name? Website and sitemaps have been submitted via Google Webmaster Tools.

Comment: should be in webmasters....

Comment: Perhaps you disalloweb crwlers to index your site using robots.txt?

Comment: What is the url?