# Google Site SEO after domain mapping change

Tags: seo, domains, google-search-console, google-sites

I have a google site https://sites.google.com/a/fractalsystems.org/buuf-decisions/

which used to be mapped http://buuf.fractalsystems.org

Since stripping away that mapping SEO has not changed and it still points to the mapped domain name instead of the site.google page.

Any idea if I can push this along or any ways of speeding it up? Am I SOL in any way?

Comment: What do you mean by "stripping away that mapping"? And "SEO has not changed"?

Comment: Stripping (I no longer have a mapping enabled) SEO has not changed = The same results come up with the old mapping

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I disagree with John. I used Google Webmaster Tools to re-add the site which was automatically verified as it is a Google Sites site.

Then, I added the Google Sites Sitemap which was generated by Google: https://sites.google.com/a/fractalsystems.org/buuf-decisions/system/feeds/sitemap

and...lo and behold...ALREADY Google is picking up the Domain mapping change.

Comment: So why didn't you try that before asking your question?

Comment: Sometimes I like to learn and then live as opposed to living and learning. Also, I was hoping for a better answer than 'Use Webmaster Tools' which I already had in mind.

Comment: This site is for helping people who have actual problems. Not for users who didn't feel like trying to help themselves first. You'll find it harder to get answers if others think you're running here before doing any work yourself.

Comment: I'm sorry, I disagree. I was asking for information because I had done my homework and couldn't find any good answers. I came here for good answers...simply offering a solution that worked doesn't mean I'm satisfied. The question still stands and I will not mark it answered until others possibly weigh in.

Answer (score 0):

Google takes a while to update their index. It could be days, weeks, and in some cases months. It varies from site to site so you won't be able to get a definitive answer to your question. But when trying to pull up your site in their index I did get Sitelinks which isn't easy to do which makes me think it will occur sooner rather then later for your site.

There is no way to speed the process up, either, so don't try to do anything to make it go faster. The only thing you can do by doing that is break stuff. Just make sure you have a redirect in place so your users can find your new location and everything will settle into place in due time.

Comment: you offer a much better solution http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/2402/i-cannot-see-my-website-in-google

Comment: That was a different question.