# How long does it take for Google Webmasters to index site after submiting sitemap?

Tags: google, search-engine-indexing, sitemap, search-engines

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why isn't my website in Google search results?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/2402/why-isnt-my-website-in-google-search-results)

I have submitted my website's sitemap to webmaster's tools.

The status on the sitemap says OK and it shows that 12 URLs have been recognized. I was wondering how long does it take for the link to get indexed? 
The indexed URL option says:

> "No data available. Please check back
>   soon."

I am not sure if it is displaying this message due to some error, or everything is fine.

Comment: Submitting a sitemap does not cause Google to index your website,  see [The Sitemap Paradox](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/4803/the-sitemap-paradox).   The best way to get your site indexed is to get it linked from other sites.

Answer (score 5):

Take a look at your logs, has GoogleBot crawled your site yet?

In my experience it takes about a week before the data is available in webmaster tools. However that does not guarantee that your data will be available in the main Google index at the same time, if at all.

Comment: Ditto, about a week for us too

Answer (score 3):

There is probably not a good answer, or at least there is probably not a good answer that you will get outside of Googleplex.  I suspect it is based on a somewhat complex algorithm that takes into account the relative popularity of your site, and that of other things are currently in the queue to be indexed.

My experience with a new site is that It usually doesn't take that long and happens in a day or two.  Make sure your sitemap is valid, and your site is up and available.

Answer (score 0):

We've also managed to get a couple of new sites indexed within a day or two of launch.

If you can post a link to your website on an existing site or your blog which is already being crawled by Google it helps a lot. Be careful of comment spam or spamming a forum though (besides many forums/blog comments include `rel="nofollow me"` in the href link so that Google doesn't follow the links).