# My site is not recognised by Google

Tags: google-index

My site http://www.mcqtoday.com is indexed by google, but even if type the full name of my site in google search it does not show my site. Bing, and Yahoo do it well. There is no crawling error I checked in google web master.

Comment: "full name of my site" - which _full name_ are you referring to? Both the domain and full `title` tag do return results for me on google.com, but your `title` uses common keywords so you are competing with many established sites. You are not yet well indexed by Google, but you don't appear to have much indexable content - the content is almost entirely generated with JavaScript. Possible duplicate: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/2402/why-isnt-my-website-in-google-search-results

Comment: There are many site which generate contents by program like javascript, but google recognises them very easily. What is the problem with this one. What do you mean by not well index?

Comment: Google can certainly index _some_ JavaScript generated content these days, but it certainly does not do this "very easily". "not well indexed" - if you do a `site:mcqtoday.com` search, Google, Bing and Yahoo return 3, 2 and 2 pages respectively. I realise this  is perhaps just an estimate, but you presumably have more than 3 pages?

Answer (score 1):

What are your SEO targeted terms? Looking at your site, I don't see you optimising for any terms at all. In your title tag, "Multiple choice questions" are your first three words. Are these really your most targeted keywords?

There isn't very much content at all to explain what the site is and who it's for. You need an "about" page full of content describing what your site is about. Your only descriptive content, "This site provides objective type question-answer..." is inside a `<p>` tag when it should be inside a `<h1>` tag.

There appears to be no link back to your "home" page from internal pages. This can definitely cause problems with crawling. At least make your logo link back to the "home" page.

I don't see a sitemap linked to on the site. Have you made one? Definitely get that in your footer links. Make an XML sitemap and submit to Google.

Oh no!

```
    http://www.mcqtoday.com/tableDriver.php?table=polscience&name=Political%20Science
```

I'm going to be honest with you. Stop everything you're doing and fix those URLs if you want to get indexed properly by the search engines. That URL should look like this:

```
    http://www.mcqtoday.com/political-science/
```

Get anything with .php out of the URLs. Get ?, =, and & out of your URLs. Get those ugly %20 (caused by spaces) out of your URLs. No file extensions, no variables, no mixed cases, and no HTML special characters in  the URL.

Right now your priorities are:

1. Fix the URL scheme
2. Get a link back to the home page on every page
3. Make an about page describing your site
4. Make a site map and put it in the footer links
5. Make an XML site map and submit at Google Webmaster

These are just the basics. Let me know when they're done and I'll have another look.

Comment: "fix those URLs if you want to get indexed" - there is a problem with the URLs, but simply making them look static (removing the URL params etc.) will not necessarily help SEO that much. It will help users and click throughs but not with getting indexed. Google states this in their blog: [Dynamic URLs vs. static URLs](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.co.uk/2008/09/dynamic-urls-vs-static-urls.html).

Comment: However, a big problem with the URLs is the `name` param, which _directly_ controls the page heading - this can be set to anything and there is no canonical URL set, so potentially creating an almost infinite number of almost duplicate pages (not to mention possible XSS attacks). This needs to be resolved before any attempt to make user-friendly URLs. At least with URL parameters Google can be configured to ignore them, if they are part of a static-looking URL then it's an even bigger problem.

Comment: Fixing them sooner rather than later will help him get the correct URLs indexed. 

OP: http://www.mcqtoday.com/tableDriver.php?table=history&name=Porn

Comment: I have completed all the advised steps. Please have a look and guide me. Thanks

Comment: I don't see any changes yet.

Comment: No dear see it nicely, may be you are looking cache version. Please have another look

Comment: Hello! can you help me

Comment: Good work so far, but I still see file extensions in your URLs. Are you using a PHP framework here?