# Website Not Showing for Keywords in Google Search

Tags: google-search, keywords, ranking

I have a Website `www.rushinformation.com` 4 Months old and I always update my Website almost Everyday...But the Problem is that When I type my keyword 'Rushinformation' only in Google Search Results it is Not Shown anywhere in search Results.

However when I type `rushinformation.com` or `www.rushinformation.com` it displays my site...

I have submitted website to Webmaster tools and Analytics with my sitemap...So please tell me how to fix this problem.

Comment: Welcome to this site, Pankaj.  What you have asked is a FAQ.  Please see: [Why isn't my website in Google search results?](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/2402/why-isnt-my-website-in-google-search-results) and [What are the best ways to increase a site's position in Google?](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/2/what-are-the-best-ways-to-increase-a-sites-position-in-google)

Answer (score 1):

You searching for words are that non dictionary since there is no space between 'rushinformation'

I can clearly see your site is ranking fine for 'rushinformation' without the .com

You need to click `Search instead for Rushinformation` as default Google is changing your search to 'Rush Information' with the space and your site does not yet rank for these keywords as your site is new and doesn't qualify for those rankings yet....

You can view the [search results here](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=Rushinformation&hl=en&sa=X&nfpr=1&spell=) and as you can see Google is automatically suggesting `Did you mean: Rush Information`.

Comment: -1 for a correct answer.... got to love the hater who -1 lots of my answers..

Comment: Thanks For Your Reply Sir....So can You tell Me How Long I have to Wait so that my site is shown in search Results for the Keywords only....also my site is Not Indexed in Bing and Yahoo even after submitting the Sitemaps to Bing Webmaster tools...Is there any Problem with the Domain Name or will it Get Fixed soon automatically ?