# Google not reading my website Content and Title, Meta tag and Description also?

Tags: google, content

I have a new website and my website Home page content, Meta tag also not reading google and not index, any one can help me my website: http://www.packerandmoversindelhi.in

Comment: Google reads your website and it is indexed, proof [here](http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=info%3Ahttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.packerandmoversindelhi.in%2F&hl=en).

Comment: What you have asked is a frequently asked question.  Please see [Why isn't my website in Google search results?](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/2402/14543).