# Changing GoDaddy Webmaster tools options

Tags: google, google-search-console, google-search, search-results

A client of mine (for school) has a website hosted on GoDaddy which we wants my team to help him increase his marketability on Google, because currently, when his company name is Google searched no relevant results are displayed.

So we were going to setup Google Webmaster Tools for him, so we can help him get there. Now we logged into his GoDaddy dashboard, and it turned out he already had one setup through GoDaddy, where they assigned him a gmail account.

I cannot figure out why his site won't show up at all on Google. Does anyone know why it isn't, like what kind of settings can I change to help him out? Also, we were trying to change the gmail account his Webmaster Tools is associated with, is this possible?

Ultimately, I'm trying to get his site seen on Google, through the Webmaster Tools, but i cannot figure out why it hasn't worked yet. Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Google Webmaster isn't required to get your site into their search results since Google has many ways of finding new websites though dns and name servers. However [submitting a sitemap to Google](http://support.google.com/sites/answer/100283?hl=en) 'MAY' speed up the process but new sites normally take 2-4 weeks to appear into the search results and even then they can end up in a '[sandbox effect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sandbox_effect)' which can further the delay. Additionally you can submit the site using [Google's Add URL page](http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/submit-url) but again... This doesn't necessary speed up the process, The site is new and Google will get around to the site in question when it has resources free to do so.

Your first point of call should be check the site and ensuring Google can index it, common reasons are normally:

- Time (wait 2-4 weeks, Google isn't real time for new sites and takes a while).
- robots.txt is blocking Google
- noindex is used somewhere within the HTML

Additionally this question has been asked over and over and [I recommend you check out Why isn't my website in Google search results](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/2402/why-isnt-my-website-in-google-search-results)? which should give you many other answers to the ones I have provided.