# Multilingual subdmain on different hosting server: will this be indexed by search engines?

Tags: seo, multilingual

I have a Japanese language sub-domain: ja.example.com, which is hosted by server A.

The root domain (example.com) is hosted by server B.

They have completely different IP addresses: (e.g.) 205.56.78.15 vs. 56.45.03.12.

Will the sub-domain be indexed by search engines?

The sub-domain has been live for one month and there have been no visits by organic searches.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no limit on how many sub domains you can index and languages do not matter. Just ensure the content is unique and not converted using automated translators. Ensure you check out [Why isn't my website in Google search results](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/2402/why-isnt-my-website-in-google-search-results/)? which will cover reasons why it might of not be indexed as of yet.

Comment: My question really was whether a subdomain gets indexed properly if it is hosted by a different server (DNS redirect). Thanks.