# SEO for short-life pages

Tags: google-search-console, search-engine-indexing, google-index, automation

I have website where I post offers. Those offers have short life. For example 2 days, sometimes less. I am using `<expires>` tag in my `sitemap.xml`.

Is there a way, how can I programatically post request to google to take new urls in account?

Example:

```
mysite.com/offer/15-10-12/12-00
```

This link is valid until 12:00 2015/10/12. I need the page indexed as soon as possible. In webmaster tools I found feature to manually add page to index, but I prefer to don't hack it to do this programatically.

Comment: There are [a bunch of ways](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/2403/1253) to tell Google these new pages exist. But that doesn't mean they will be indexed. (You also can't add pages to their index. You can only let them know you would *like* a page to be indexed). But inclusion is never guaranteed and out of your control. Unless your site is well established these pages may never be indexed.

Comment: John is perfectly right! I will offer this however. The links that seem to get the most attention are the links on the home page. If you can link to these offers from your home page, they, and your home page will get more attention. But if there are too many, then perhaps just a few most important offers and a link to a page of offers. But this must happen for a moderately significant period before Google will see your home page and/or offers pages as being fresh enough to index each day. Just a suggestion.

Comment: As a thought, short lived pages can never rank. It is important that you find a way that your non-short lived pages rank and that you have enough of them to constitute a good rank for your site. Your short lived pages will help to keep your site fresh. You must build relevancy otherwise. It will be a challenge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The single thing you can do under described circumstances is to submit your page to index using the search console function "[fetch and render the page with Google](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/googlebot-fetch)".

I would like to know, what the SEO-sense you implicit with indexing of such short-living pages? Even if Google indexes your pages, do you expect any organic traffic from it?

In my opinion, there will be no worth mentioning traffic, so i would rather drive Adwords to such pages.

Comment: This is good point. It is silly to expect organic traffic to page that lives only few days.