# Would could Google not index an AJAX news feed after 1 month?

Tags: seo, google-search, php, javascript, ajax

I have a website that in `page1.php` uses a news API from other website. It has JS calling a PHP method like this:

```
<script id="mdval" 
src="http://example.com/parvazproject/parvaz.php?c=fd85ba02169c6907450522dc33d35765"
type="text/javascript" dval="sourceval">
```

This page is basically AJAX loaded. News loads via the AJAX method. `page1.php` appears in Google Analytics,  but it`s entire content not indexed in Google search after one month. Links in the loaded content do not get indexed.

UPDATE:

I tested page in Fetch as Google tool. I selected fetch and render for a page that uses ajax. Googlebot saw the page just like visitors with all contents and images. I clicked on "submit to index" for indexing page. Now after one day I searched URL in Google and Google listed it.

But Now the problem is here that Google just shows URL and meta description in search results and not shows any content of the page.

please search this link in google. www.neginkoodebasir.ir/more?naapi= گیاهان مورد استفاده در تهیه کود سبز (بخش دوم)

[image]
[image]

Comment: There are good answers to these similar questions: [Why isn't my website in Google search results?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/2402/why-isnt-my-website-in-google-search-results) and [Why aren't search engines indexing my content?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/43350/why-arent-search-engines-indexing-my-content) although they don't address the AJAX portion of this question.

Comment: Is this news feed built with content that will be unique to your site, or is the same news feed that gets included by many different sites?

Comment: please read update

Comment: Is the content on your page unique to your website, or is the AJAX writing in stories that are also on other sites?

Comment: content is the AJAX and is stored on other site. but content is unique for me and loads just in my website.

Answer (score 1):

Google tends to show the content of the meta description on the SERP, which is what makes this field so important for SEO. Google may show content snippets instead of the meta description in cases where the content matches the search keywords and they are not in the description.

If you omit the meta description the search result description be selected from the page's contents instead and will be completely at Google's discretion.

It is not ideal to serve the same meta description for every page, so if you are not dynamically generating this tag for each page it may be best to omit the tag and let Google pull the description from your code instead.