# How to understand why my page is not ranking with any word despite all the work?

Tags: seo, search-results, google-ranking

I have a 2500 words page full of focused content, photos, videos, links etc. . The majority of the keyphrases are centered around one topic "content creation services". But no matter what keyword I search for, my site never appears in serp and it is confusing.

The url is indexed. I have long article. I have links on the page (internal and external). I still don't have backlinks. I want to rank it in a "local serp" so I expect it to rank easier! but apparently there's a problem that I haven't discovered.

I'll appreciate if you tell me what to do to solve this issue and rank my page.

Comment: How long has the page existed?  I've seen it take a couple of months before pages rank.  Have you tried to see if Google even knows about your page? I.e, have you tried site:example.com?

Comment: About 2 weeks. Yes I've tried site:mysite.com, nothing shows. Only my homepage on the list.

Comment: If site:example.com doesn't show your page, I doubt that it's indexed.  What makes you believe that it is?  Have you looked in Google Search Console?  You mentioned that it has internal links, but are there links from your home page to the subject page, even if you have to travel through 2-3 other links?

Comment: what makes me believe is google search console message for that url: "It can appear in Google Search results (if not subject to a manual action or removal request) with all relevant enhancements". And yes, I have it on the main navigation, also in the middle of my homepage as a big section

Comment: You may just need to give it more time.  Normally, anything Google has crawled shows up with the site command, but it may not show up in search results for awhile.  You might also look in your server logs for any errors from Google IP addresses.You may also want to read https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/2402/why-isnt-my-website-in-google-search-results for anything else I may have missed.

Comment: Thanks a lot dear Trebor. I appreciate it.

Comment: Yes, you should wait a bit longer, everything else appears to be in order. Just keep in mind that the "site:mysite.com" command is extremely unreliable and should not be used to see the indexing status of any page (according to Google themselves), you need to wait/use for Search Console.