# Blog posts not getting index in google

Tags: google-search, search-engine-indexing, blog

I have a blogger at jsloop24.blogspot.com. I have added the site to google search console. Only the main home page is getting indexed. There is only one result for the site (site:jsloop24.blogspot.com). I had custom domain for this blog earlier. It was indexing fine with all the pages and post urls in google. I also tried wordpress at jsloop42.wordpress.com and it's the same result. Only the front page is indexed. Any idea what is causing this and how to fix this? Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why isn't my website in Google search results?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/2402/why-isnt-my-website-in-google-search-results)